# How on frame keep same behavior when printWhenExpression is false as if it does not exists?

Tags: jasper-reports

[image]

So I have a detail band with two frames, the first frame has several elements including a subreport, the second frame only has a textfield.

The issue I'm having is, if i remove the second frame from the band all the content remains in the same page. If i add the second frame and use the printonly expression to not show it, it changes the entire content to the next page.
Is there a way to force that, if the second frame is empty to maintain the behavior as if didn't exist at all?

```
<band height="160" splitType="Prevent">
        <property name="local_mesure_unitheight" value="pixel"/>
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.layout" value="com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.layout.FreeLayout"/>
        <frame>
            <reportElement isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="0" y="1" width="556" height="116" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="3aca49ee-4b55-452c-a8c6-5cc252c4175c">
                <property name="local_mesure_unitheight" value="pixel"/>
                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
            </reportElement>
            <subreport>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="2" y="65" width="160" height="51" uuid="438d3f08-7b8a-4b61-b17f-19993aa5abe4">
                    <property name="local_mesure_unitx" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="cm"/>
                </reportElement>
                <subreportParameter name="DOC_ID">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{DOC_ID}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <subreportParameter name="IS_RUNNING_LOCAL">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{IS_RUNNING_LOCAL}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JREmptyDataSource()]]></dataSourceExpression>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{IS_RUNNING_LOCAL} ? "/Reports/Common/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxSub.jasper" : "repo:/Reports/Common/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxSub"]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                <reportElement style="Default" positionType="Float" mode="Transparent" x="1" y="1" width="552" height="30" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" forecolor="#000000" backcolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="837c85bf-7a2a-4eb5-919d-bd16d4bc64f2">
                    <property name="local_mesure_unitwidth" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="local_mesure_unity" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="px"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="cm"/>
                    <property name="local_mesure_unitheight" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <box padding="0" topPadding="0" leftPadding="0" bottomPadding="0" rightPadding="0"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Justified" verticalAlignment="Top" rotation="None" markup="html">
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="10" isBold="false" isItalic="false" isUnderline="false" isStrikeThrough="false" pdfFontName="Helvetica" pdfEncoding="Cp1252" isPdfEmbedded="false"/>
                    <paragraph lineSpacing="Single" lineSpacingSize="1.0" firstLineIndent="0" leftIndent="0" rightIndent="0" spacingBefore="0" spacingAfter="0" tabStopWidth="40"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement style="Default" positionType="Float" mode="Transparent" x="2" y="43" width="511" height="17" forecolor="#000000" backcolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="3e1c3952-6578-4d5f-85a3-d706fc5a5fbb">
                    <property name="local_mesure_unitwidth" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                    <property name="local_mesure_unitx" value="cm"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="cm"/>
                    <property name="local_mesure_unitheight" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <box padding="0" topPadding="0" leftPadding="0" bottomPadding="0" rightPadding="0"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Justified" verticalAlignment="Top" rotation="None" markup="html">
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="9" isBold="false" isItalic="false" isUnderline="false" isStrikeThrough="false" pdfFontName="Helvetica" pdfEncoding="Cp1252" isPdfEmbedded="false"/>
                    <paragraph lineSpacing="Single" lineSpacingSize="1.0" firstLineIndent="0" leftIndent="0" rightIndent="0" spacingBefore="0" spacingAfter="0" tabStopWidth="40"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["testetestestestestestes"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </frame>
        <frame>
            <reportElement positionType="Float" x="1" y="120" width="555" height="40" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="c3bf96ce-dd19-41f1-bf13-fe1dd46d8d4e">
                <property name="local_mesure_unitheight" value="pixel"/>
                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                <property name="local_mesure_unitwidth" value="pixel"/>
                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$P{COD_DOC}.equals("xx_xxx_xxx")]]></printWhenExpression>
            </reportElement>
            <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement positionType="Float" isPrintRepeatedValues="false" mode="Transparent" x="1" y="0" width="551" height="39" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="c1ab35b8-31a6-41e9-a260-71bbcab8692e">
                    <property name="local_mesure_unitwidth" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$P{COD_DOC}.equals("xx_xxx_xxx")]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Justified">
                    <font size="10"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["PS: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </frame>
    </band>
```

Comment: Pleae post your XML file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to force that, if the second frame is empty to maintain the behavior as if didn't exist at all?

The solution to this is to use multiple detail bands and set the `printWhenExpression` to the detail band

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="TestParams" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="f85bc6aa-5060-4485-bd99-bd5de1734ef1">
<queryString>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <detail>
        <band height="116">
           <break>
            <reportElement x="0" y="5" width="100" height="1" uuid="fb9c89cd-1b6a-44f5-82a9-99e9996229e3">
                <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$P{COD_DOC}.equals("xx_xxx_xxx")]]></printWhenExpression>
            </reportElement>
           </break>
            <frame>
                <reportElement x="0" y="10" width="200" height="116" uuid="e6890adf-6ff1-49f6-9c47-ba6f171a2c60"/>
            </frame>
        </band>
        <band height="40">
            <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$P{COD_DOC}.equals("xx_xxx_xxx")]]></printWhenExpression>
            <frame>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="200" height="40" uuid="d9f8ba4a-e435-49ff-9ff7-d23e55aecc52"/>
            </frame>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

This way if second component is not showing/printed the whole band (height) will be removed and it will behave as only first band exists.

Comment: The thing is how do you force the two bands to change page if the second one is to show? That's the behaviour i want.

Comment: @Maxrunner I have edited added a page break also if the other bad is displayed, however normally (if you are not sure that it always should break, fixed content), you can handle dynamic page breaks with groups, groups have a parameter `minHeightToStartNewPage` that can you help decided when to break. However your question as it is currently and based on your comment I guess a page break is enough.

Comment: thanks, the solution was to put the break in a new detail/band.